# why make behaves different with quotes?

Tags: makefile

I know quotes are not supposed to be used within `Makefile`, but just out of curiosity, why `make` behaves differently with `make foobar` and `make`. See detailed code below.

Makefile:

```
TARGET = 'foobar'

$(TARGET): foobar.cpp
    g++ -g $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm foobar
```

output:

```
$ make
g++ -g foobar.cpp -o 'foobar'           <-- correct
$ make clean
rm foobar
$ make foobar
g++     foobar.cpp   -o foobar          <-- incorrect but works. Why?
$ make clean
rm foobar
$ make baz                              <-- doesn't work, which is normal
make: *** No rule to make target 'baz'.  Stop.
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only "works" because the shell is stripping the single quotes from your first example for you.

The quotes are *literally* in the value of the `$(TARGET)` make variable. make doesn't dequote the right-hand side of the `TARGET = 'foobar'` assignment.

You can see this by using `$(info $(TARGET))` in your makefile.

So your target line:

```
$(TARGET): foobar.cpp
```

is creating a target with the name `'foobar'` and not `foobar` like you expect.

This is why running `make` does the "right" thing and `make foobar` does something else.

`make foobar` is running the make [built in](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) rule for `%: %.cpp`.

The fact that your default `'foobar'` target works to create `foobar` is because the *shell* sees the single quotes and strips them.

You'll notice that if you make `make; make` make will build your `'foobar'` target *twice* but `make foobar; make foobar` will tell you there is nothing to be done the second time. That's because the first target creates a file *different* from what make is expecting.

If you were to quote `$@` in your recipe line you would see different behavior.

```
$(TARGET): foobar.cpp
    g++ -g $^ -o '$@'
```

for example would have make run `g++ -g foobar.cpp -o ''foobar''` and generate a `foobar` file while

```
$(TARGET): foobar.cpp
    g++ -g $^ -o "$@"
```

would have make run `g++ -g foobar.cpp -o "'foobar'"` and generate a `'foobar'` file (which would cause `make; make` to report nothing to be done for the second `make` run).

You want the quotes in the recipe line not in the variable here.

```
TARGET = foobar

$(TARGET): foobar.cpp
    g++ -g $^ -o '$@'

clean:
    rm foobar
```

That being said since you can't have spaces in make target names (not reliably at least) the need for those single quotes (or any quoting) is diminished since you only need it if the filename contains shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

It's because make uses a default rule when it does not find specific rules to build a target.

You can compile `program` from `program.cpp` even without or with an empty `Makefile`. Try

```
make -f /dev/null foobar
```

The default rules are specified by POSIX and your make implementation has probably some of its own.

Trying to build baz fails, because none of the default rules knows how to build a `baz.c` or `baz.cpp` or any of the other built-in source files that could be used to build `baz`.

Comment: This is correct but only addresses part of the question. That's parts two and three of the question covered now. =)

Comment: So the "incorrect but works" case actually doesn't really find the rule to build the target, and falls to default rules?

Comment: @wlnirvana Yes, there's only a rule for `'target'` (with the quotes as part of the name), but not for `target` (without the quotes).